# Loading a compiled class in Java and deserializing it's instance from a file

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, classloader

I need to have an app that during run-time can load another class and deserialize one of it's instance successfuly so that it can run it's methods and read the member variables.

From what I noticed, you can not serialize methods in Java, so I'm thinking about serializing the class instance in `project2`, load the compiled class with `ClassLoader` in `project1`, instantiate it and assign the deserialized instance from `porject2` in `project1` to the instantiated loaded class.

The serialized class will inherit the same parent class in both projects.

Is this the best way to go? It's a school project so the requirements are that my app can accept any other type of class without changing the code.

TL;DR: My plan is to load a compiled class with the ClassLoader so that my project knows about that class (specifically the methods inside) and then load that serialized class instance inside the project so that I can get the data from the instance and together with the loaded class (now I know the methods aswell), run the methods on the deserialized instance.

Comment: Thanks; and gratitude expressed ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. The ability to call a method on some object isn't related to serialization **at all**.

What I mean: the method implementation is **not** part of the serialized data! Java serialization only writes **field** data into that output stream.

The **implementation** of a method **only** depends on the **class** file of some Java class. You can serialize and deserialize your objects as often as you want to - but what happens when you call a method on such an object is **only** determined by the class file that the corresponding class loader loaded for you when *first* accessing the corresponding class.

If your goal is really just about "one class dumps an object into a binary representation"; and another piece of code loads that binary data; turns it into an object; to access that object; then you do **not** need two projects. You also do not need to worry about "the methods being" there. As long as your ClassLoader *knows* the class of objects to be de-serialized, everything will just work. Just pick an example tutorial, like this [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) and work through it.

But: **when** your requirement is to invoke methods or access fields of **arbitrary** objects; then you don't look into serialization, but into Java [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

But a word of warning there: reflections sounds easy, but be assured: there are many many ways for you to write slightly wrong code. And because reflection is basically a **runtime** thing, the java compiler doesn't help much. You write code that looks reasonable, it compiles, you run it, and you get exceptions throw at you.

In that sense, reflection is an **advanced** topic in the Java curriculum; and I think you should rather step back and clarify with your teachers what exactly they expect from you.

Given your latest updates: then simply look into that tutorial about serialization (and forget about the reflection part). And to answer your question: yes, that sounds like a viable approach. Can't say more; as you are not sharing code so far.

Comment: Hi. My plan is to load a compiled class with the ClassLoader so that my project knows about that class (specifically the methods inside) and then load that serialized class instance inside the project so that I can get the data from the instance and together with the loaded class (now I know the methods aswell), run the methods on the deserialized instance. I have edited my question, I wanted to say " load another class and deserialize one of it's instance"

Comment: See my updates. But please understand: we help with specific problems ... and in that sense, your request is actually too unspecific.